# Solspace Calendar does not displaying past events

Tags: solspace, solspace-calendar

When I use this code (specifying an entire year of past and upcoming events), Calendar only displays upcoming events and fails to display events which have already passed.

```
{exp:calendar:events date_range_start="2013-08-01" date_range_end="2014-08-01"}
```

(The behavior is the same when I use the `{exp:calendar:cal}` tag pair.)

**How can I get past events to show up in my event list?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a fool — My client had (unbeknownst to me) added expiration dates to all the entries. (Calendar is behaving exactly as expected, showing all ***non-expired*** events within the provided date range.)

In this case, I shall clear out the expiration dates from the entries and clarify to my client that the Calendar takes care of both the starting and ending dates.

The [`show_expired`](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#show-expired) parameter would also work.